# No Windows 8 Apps will start - Windows.Launch for registered

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui, windows-8-apps

I am unable to start any of the Windows 8 "Metro" applications anymore on any of the users on my system.

This includes the Store, and the PC Settings application.  When I try to run these apps, it quits to desktop every time and two error logs are written:

> Activation of app windows.immersivecontrolpanel_cw5n1h2txyewy!microsoft.windows.immersivecontrolpanel failed with error: This app does not support the contract specified or is not installed. See the Microsoft-Windows-TWinUI/Operational log for additional information.

And in Microsoft-Windows-TWinUI/Operational:

> The app windows.immersivecontrolpanel_cw5n1h2txyewy!microsoft.windows.immersivecontrolpanel is not registered for the Windows.Launch contract or is not installed.

I am trying to run these apps as a administrator (not the local administrator, that account is disabled) with UAC enabled.  So far, I've tried:

- `sfc /scannow` - no issues detected
- `DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth` - completed without error
- Creating a new user and trying to run apps there - same result
- Updating Graphics Drivers
- Running Windows Update
- Ran the "Windows Store Apps" troubleshooter, it always says there might be an issue with my graphics drivers, even though I did a fresh insall of the latest GeForce drivers

Chrome in "Windows 8 Mode" works, however.

Comment: Were any errors reported after running the `sfc` and `dism` commands?

Comment: No errors were detected with sfc, and dism completed successfully.

Comment: The answer to this similar question solved my issues: http://superuser.com/a/865752/173416

Comment: possible duplicate of [Metro apps on Windows 8.1 crash on start](http://superuser.com/questions/844696/metro-apps-on-windows-8-1-crash-on-start)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I was never able to solve this issue.  If you are having this problem you will need to reinstall windows.

Answer (score 0):

I've found answer here http://blogs.technet.com/b/ouc1too/archive/2013/10/19/windows-app-store-doesn-t-load-after-8-1-upgrade.aspx
You just need to change application manifest path, in the command, to fix all other applications