# Metro apps on Windows 8.1 crash on start

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, modern-ui

After a while Windows 8.1 apps won't open anymore. Opening the app will show the splash screen and then exit to the desktop with the icon still present in the task bar. A restart temporarily solved the problem.

After checking the windows event log I found this error message, but am not able to glean anything useful from it.

> Activation of application microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps_8wekyb3d8bbwe!Microsoft.WindowsLive.Mail failed with error: This application does not support the contract specified or is not installed. See the Microsoft-Windows-TWinUI/Operational log for additional information.

The additional log information shows the following.

> The application DefaultBrowser_NOPUBLISHERID!Microsoft.InternetExplorer.Default is not registered for the Windows.Launch contract or is not installed.

This seems to happen for every app installed, does anyone have a fix for this issue?

I've also looked at this question but without any luck: [Metro apps crash on startup, driver or permissions issue?](https://superuser.com/questions/432859/metro-apps-crash-on-startup-driver-or-permissions-issue)

Comment: Looks like this might be a solution
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2798317

Comment: Sadly it looks like I have a different problem. I've verified all the permissions are correct. Note that the apps do work after a restart, so permissions didn't seem like a likely culprit anyway.

Comment: http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2013/10/11/what-to-do-if-your-windows-8-modern-app-fails-to-start.aspx

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue on Windows 10 Technical Preview.

After some digging, I've found answers on [MS Community](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-windows_store/windows-store-app-wont-open/0eb9e9de-6ffc-471c-ad56-bab34efacb64?page=4) and in [this blog entry](https://somethingdifferent.wordpress.com/2014/12/01/how-to-fix-metro-apps-minimizing-on-launch/). Just to summarize - to fix a single application (PC Settings in this case), type in Administrative Powershell console:

> Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register $Env:SystemRoot\ImmersiveControlPanel\AppxManifest.xml -Verbose

For fixing all applications run:

> Get-AppxPackage | % { Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppxManifest.xml" -verbose }

Comment: Can you explain the reason this fixes the problem? What it seems to do seems semi-hostile to a secure environment

Comment: In the second command: `Get-AppxPackage` gets a list of installed app packages (.appx) and `Add-AppxPackage` installs an app package. So the command kind of reinstalls metro applications, but with DevelopmentMode disabled. It shouldn't be harmful in a sense that it won't install anything new or remove existing apps.
And in the first command, `$Env:SystemRoot\ImmersiveControlPanelAppxManifest.xml` is just the install location of `windows.immersivecontrolpanel` package (`get-AppxPackage | ? { $_ -match "panel" }`)

Comment: Here is why I ask; At times I am unable to launch any Modern UI application, if I perform a restart, I am able to launch those same applications.  My research is tough because people have an entirely different problem caused by their various permission hacks.  I might have to try this next time it happens.

Comment: Hi, I'm using the Windows 10 Tech Preview too. My problem is after a crash I can't open the start menu nor the action center and all metro apps. However, using your script does contain many error for me `Add-AppxPackage : Deployment failed with HRESULT: 0x80073CF6, Package could not
 be registered.
error 0x80070002: Windows cannot register the package because of an internal er
ror or low memory.
NOTE: For additional information, look for [ActivityId] 1b879ac4-3f95-0001-27ef
-871b953fd001 in the Event Log or use the command line Get-AppxLog -ActivityID
At line:1 char:23` Is it normal?

Comment: Actually, after I **deleted my own userclass.dat** I am able now to use that powershell command.

Comment: I reasonably detailed answer can be found at http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_desktop/windows-10-cannot-open-start-menu-action-center/b8b56dd6-1d0b-4920-b883-78f1e6ca28b8 .  Refers to this answer.

Comment: @AnthonyHorne Hi, **It is I that created that insider thread** linking to this code, I didn't make that :( Please check my profile image if you don't believe me. Just don't put any credit on me :)

Comment: There is a little mistake in the first script. `Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register $Env:SystemRoot\ImmersiveControlPanelAppxManifest.xml -Verbose` There's a "\" missing. It should be `Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register $Env:SystemRoot\ImmersiveControlPanel\AppxManifest.xml -Verbose`